# FlinkKafakProducer's numRecordsOut is always show 0 while there are message written to Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I set up a Flink job writing some messages to a Kafka topic. It uses the FlinkKafakProducer as the sink. I validated that there are messages written to the output Kafka topic but the Flink metric `numRecordsOut` is always showing 0. Similarly, in the Flink Web UI, the bytes sent always showing 0B as well.

What is the cause for the number of records out not reflecting the actual volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numRecordsOut` metric only tracks Flink internal traffic, i.e., the number of records that are passed between Flink operators. It doesn not track records that are written to an external system (and that are hence leaving Flink).

Since this is a common reason for confusion, there are plans to address this issue soon.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So what would be the better metric to measure the actual message written by the FlinkKafakProducer to kafka topic?

Comment: I looked into the producer's code a bit. Looked like it was wrapping the kafaproducer's metrics. So I think those with prefix "KafkaProducer." would be the wrapped metrics. Those are the true metrics related to the producer I think